# mongodb complex or/and query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

So I have a collections which stores the start and end times for an event and I would like a user to be able to query for events by specifying "filter" start and end times. The query should return any events that intersect with the filter times. I thought I was building the query correctly, but it's not returning the results I want.

Example data (simplified mongo document to get the idea, times are HHMMSS):

```
{ ..., "start" : "050520", "end" : "051309" } //Should match
{ ..., "start" : "051125", "end" : "051925" } //Should match
{ ..., "start" : "052049", "end" : "052420" } //Should match
{ ..., "start" : "050000", "end" : "050500" }
{ ..., "start" : "052100", "end" : "052721" }
```

The query I tried was (Forgive me if I missed a bracket here, that's not the issue):

```
find( { $or : [ 
            { start : { $gte : "050600", $lt : "052100" } }, 
            { end : { $lt : "052100", $gt : "050600" } } 
        ] } )
```

Which only returned one of the three results. Switching the order of the $or parts ( querying against the end times before the start times) gives me two results but not all three. I seem to remember reading that for compound queries mongo throws away results that don't match the first part, before applying the second part of the query, but I thought the $or operator would handle that.
Any ideas? Is my query incorrect, is this a limitation of querying in mongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MongoDB 2.4.5 I tried the above and got back in both cases the first 2 of your "Should match" results.

I don't believe the 3rd should be returned as it would require ("052049" >= "050600" && "052049" < "052000") or ("052420" < "052000" && "052420" > "050600") neither of which evaluate to true.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
> 
> db.mycol.save({ "start" : "050520", "end" : "051309" }) 
> db.mycol.save({ "start" : "051125", "end" : "051925" })
> db.mycol.save({ "start" : "052049", "end" : "052420" }) 
> db.mycol.save({ "start" : "050000", "end" : "050500" })
> db.mycol.save({ "start" : "052100", "end" : "052721" })
>
> db.mycol.find( 
... { $or : 
... [ { $and : [ { start : { $gte : "050600" } }, { start : { $lt : "052000" } } ] }, 
...   { $and : [ { end : { $lt : "052000" } }, { end : { $gt : "050600" } } ] } 
... ] 
...     } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520528522683a40682f12b5c"), "start" : "050520", "end" : "051309" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520528522683a40682f12b5d"), "start" : "051125", "end" : "051925" }
> 
> 
> db.mycol.find( 
... { $or : 
... [     { $and : [ { end : { $lt : "052000" } }, { end : { $gt : "050600" } } ] } , 
...   { $and : [ { start : { $gte : "050600" } }, { start : { $lt : "052000" } } ] }
... ] 
...     } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520528522683a40682f12b5c"), "start" : "050520", "end" : "051309" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520528522683a40682f12b5d"), "start" : "051125", "end" : "051925" }
>
```

Comment: Hah you are right the third one shouldn't match. Hmm I'm wondering, I'm currently using MongoDB 2.2.2 which may be the problem. I'll try upgrading and verify.

Comment: The behavior for this should be identical between 2.2.2 and 2.4.5. Let me know if you see different.

Comment: Well I upgraded to 2.4.5 and it worked... So I went back to 2.2.2 and tried again and it worked as expected there too. I must have had a typo :/  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work fine, but the third one *shouldn't* match as both `start` and `end` are out of the range.

However, you can write your query more clearly and succinctly as:

```
db.test.find({ $or: [
    { start: { $gte: "050600", $lt : "052000" }}, 
    { end: { $lt: "052000", $gt: "050600" }}
]});
```

Comment: Doh! I wanted my filter to encompass that end time, I missed in the example. But this is good to know I didn't realize I could join the gte, lt operators into one statement. I think the query may not be working because I am using an out of date version of mongo.

Comment: @mike I doubt it as I don't think any of this behavior has changed in recent versions.